# Can't focus the chrome window with chrome extension api chrome.windows.update

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket, electron

I have a Chrome extension(Manifest is v2) called “TabHelper” and an Electron application called “URLOpener”.
I created a WebSocket Server in URLOpener and a WebSocket Client in TabHelper. The logic in TabHelper is to establish a WebSocket connection with the WebSocket Server in URLOpener when the browser is opened.
I send a message containing a URL to the WebSocket client in TabHelper using the WebSocket Server.
Using the Chrome extensions API in TabHelper, I create a tab with the URL and bring the window to the foreground using the Chrome extensions API: chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true}).
However, I am currently unable to bring the window containing the tab to the foreground.
It happend in most time, but it also didn't happen in some time, i cant find a pattern in which this event occurs.
Why is this happening?

I Tried using chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true}) in a timeout, it also can't work.
I tried differen versions of chrome(70, 87, 108), it performance all the same.

Comment: It can be a bug in Chrome or a mistake in your code's logic.

Comment: "It happend in most time, but it also didn't happen in some time, i cant find a pattern in which this event occurs." - We can't find a pattern, either, unless you provide us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)